# how add to list of structure in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, struct

I Write this code in `c#` , i use list of structure , but how  can i add to list with structure,i use add  to add xx,yy,size but not correct ? i need only method for add data to list of structure

```
public struct blocks
{
   public Int32 xx;
   public Int32 yy;
   public Int32 size;
};

namespace test2
{

  class Program
  {        
    static List<blocks> blocks1 = new List<blocks>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {       
        Int32 index=0;

        for (int y = 1; y < 5; y++)

               for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
               {
                    blocks1[index].xx +=( x * 2); // store start point (x) of block
                    blocks1[index].yy += (y *2); // store start point (y) of block
                    blocks1[index].size +=( 2); // store block size
                    index++;
               }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In your example "blocks1" is an array so you cannot do "blocks1.xb.Add( x * 2);". Probably you are trying to do "blocks1[index].xb.Add( x * 2);" but xb is an int so there is no Add method directly available to xb. So probably you are trying to do "blocks1[index].xb += ( x * 2);" Also you have not defined "index". Please do so, so that we are able to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. An updated question with these info will be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are trying to achieve but not very sure. If this is not what you need then please update your question with the information as per my comment

```
public struct blocks
{
    public Int32 xb;
    public Int32 yb;
    public Int32 size;
};

namespace test
{

    class Program
    {
        static List<blocks> blocks1;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            blocks1 = new List<blocks>();
            for (int y = 1; y < 5; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 1; x < 5; x++)
                {
                    blocks newBlock = new blocks();

                    newBlock.xb = x * 2;
                    newBlock.yb = y * 2;
                    newBlock.size = 2;

                    blocks1.Add(newBlock);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `List<blocks> blocks1 = new List<blocks>()` since that is a data structure that you can just add to as needed.

You can add to it like so:

```
blocks newBlock = new blocks();
blocks1.Add(newBlock) ;
```

Comment: thank you, but how can I add to list i write blocks1.xb.Add( x * block_size); but not correct ??

Comment: I have added an example for how to add to the list

Comment: ok, I do not understand  how can i add element xb,yb,size to list structure, I update my question